# Is there a noun form for "fine-grained"?

Tags: phrases, nouns, word-formation

For example I want to say: ...the level of (fine-grained in noun) that is needed...  I wonder if the word "grainery" will work.

Comment: We need some context. In certain cases, *precision* might fit, but your usage may require other terms. *Granularity* is a generic term that does not presume *fineness*.

Answer (score 6):

I think you're looking for "***granularity***".

[Wiktionary's entry for *granularity*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/granularity) reads:

> ### Noun
>
> *granularity (countable and uncountable, plural granularities)*
>
> (uncountable) *The condition of being granular*
>
> (countable) *The extent to which something is granular*

And Wikipedia elaborates in its [article on granularity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Granularity):

> ***Granularity*** is the extent to which a system is broken down into small parts, either the system itself or its description or observation. It is the extent to which a larger entity is subdivided. For example, a yard broken into inches has finer granularity than a yard broken into feet.
>
> ***Coarse-grained*** systems consist of fewer, larger components than **fine-grained** systems; a coarse-grained description of a system regards large subcomponents while a fine-grained description regards smaller components of which the larger ones are composed.